# Draw an UIImage on top of a subView and interact with a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a `ViewController` with a `UIScrollView` and 3 subviews.
I've declared the size of the UIScrollView to have the 3 views by horizontal scrolling.
I'm trying to draw a new image on top of each sub view and when the view will be scrolled I would like that the new image will be scrolled with the subview.
Right now, I managed to draw the new image, but it remains static even when I scroll the views.

```
x = [button frame].origin.x;
y = [button frame].origin.y;
check = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+100,y+100, 20, 20)];
check.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];    
[self.view addSubview:check];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't draw it in your scroll view. Draw it in your custom UIImageView subclass. Or add subviews to your image views.